# uwsgi + xdv integration

Tags: plone, uwsgi, xdv

i'm trying to configure uwsgi + xdv as a frontend for plone and other applications (this is why i don't use collective.xdv)

any hints?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use XDV via a WSGI proxy, you probably want to take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dv.xdvserver. The configuration instructions are for PasteDeploy, but if you are familiar with uWSGI you should be able to adjust them.

Note that Plone itself doesn't yet support WSGI, so it will run via its own normal web server.

Comment: Thanks Hanno, i already had a look at dv.xdvserver and trying to let it working under PasteDeploy. It seems i'll have to write a custom wsgi app for uwsgi.